# Mysql using COUNT insde CASE

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use count inside CASE, here is my query. gives me an error #1111

```
SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.date_entered,t1.date_modified, t1.adresse,t1.adresse_state,t1.adresse_city,t1.adresse_postalcode,t1.hausnummer,t1.center_lat,t1.center_long, t3.name as street_name,t3.strasse,t3.primaerstr 
FROM hi_haus as t1 
LEFT JOIN hi_haus_hi_strasse as t2 ON (t2.hi_haus_id = t1.id)
LEFT JOIN hi_strasse as t3 ON (t3.id = t2.hi_strasse_id)
WHERE t1.adresse !='' AND t1.adresse IS NOT NULL AND t1.adresse NOT LIKE '%bau%' AND t1.id IN ('58e722d6-44f5-4e24-8861-5cd4a6f07cbc','4d0a79ee-decf-49b1-8b4b-a912b278ffec')
AND t3.primaerstr =
CASE
WHEN count(t1.id) > '1' THEN t3.primaerstr='0'
ELSE
t3.primaerstr = '1'
END
GROUP BY t1.id
```

What i need is to get the primaerstr '0' if id is repeating more than once.

Comment: You can select only those columns which you group by. In this case, you are grouping by t1.id and selecting t1.name, t1.date etc.

Comment: i am slecting t1.id also, the query works if i don't use CASE, and to be specific using count in case

Comment: are you counting based on the joins or a just table regardless of the contents?

Comment: yes counting based on joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT t1.id,t1.name,t1.date_entered,t1.date_modified, t1.adresse,t1.adresse_state,t1.adresse_city,t1.adresse_postalcode,t1.hausnummer,t1.center_lat,t1.center_long, t3.name as street_name,t3.id,t3.strasse,t3.primaerstr FROM hi_haus as t1 LEFT JOIN hi_haus_hi_strasse as t2 ON (t2.hi_haus_id = t1.id) LEFT JOIN hi_strasse as t3 ON (t3.id = t2.hi_strasse_id) WHERE t1.adresse !='' AND t1.adresse IS NOT NULL AND t1.adresse NOT LIKE '%bau%' AND t1.id IN ('58e722d6-44f5-4e24-8861-5cd4a6f07cbc','5d492f56-c26e-4c03-b3ec-e1d9b0c6f060','fc87b46a-5fe8-4ed0-b3f4-f6fbb0d6919d')AND t3.primaerstr != (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(hi_haus_id) FROM hi_haus_hi_strasse WHERE hi_haus_id = t1.id) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE '' END)ORDER BY t1.id,t1.date_modified DESC LIMIT 30;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`SELECT  t1.id ,
        t1.name ,
        t1.date_entered ,
        t1.date_modified ,
        t1.adresse ,
        t1.adresse_state ,
        t1.adresse_city ,
        t1.adresse_postalcode ,
        t1.hausnummer ,
        t1.center_lat ,
        t1.center_long ,
        t3.name AS street_name ,
        t3.strasse ,
        t3.primaerstr
FROM    hi_haus AS t1 ,
        ( SELECT    id ,
                    COUNT(*) AS count
          FROM      hi_haus
          GROUP BY id
        ) AS subquery
        LEFT JOIN hi_haus_hi_strasse AS t2 ON ( t2.hi_haus_id = t1.id )
        LEFT JOIN hi_strasse AS t3 ON ( t3.id = t2.hi_strasse_id )
WHERE   t1.adresse != ''
        AND t1.adresse IS NOT NULL
        AND t1.adresse NOT LIKE '%bau%'
        AND t1.id IN ( '58e722d6-44f5-4e24-8861-5cd4a6f07cbc',
                       '4d0a79ee-decf-49b1-8b4b-a912b278ffec' )
        AND (( t3.primaerstr = 0
              AND t1.id = subquery.id
              AND subquery.count > 1 )
              OR (t3.primaerstr = 1
              AND t1.id = subquery.id
              AND subquery.count = 0)
            )
GROUP BY t1.id`

Comment: Thanks for your help Abhijith but still error #1054

Comment: #1054 is unknown column. Check if any of the column is misspelled. Sorry, cannot spoon feed here

Comment: well, i have already checked if any column is misspelled. But unfortunetely that's not the case. I am counting id on basis of joins, i think that might be the problem. but thanks again